# Data-frame Object has no Attribute

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am trying to call Dataframe columns for analysis using Pandas. I uploaded a CSV file, however every time It gives me this error `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'X'`
 How can I make every column available for analysis and why does this always happen.

`proportion_women_survived = float(sum(women.survived))/len(women)` This is one example. I `read_CSV('Train.csv)` into Python editor and the columns are shown when I `data.head()` however not one column unless I do this:

```
[{newCols = data.columns.values
newCols[-1] = 'PassengerId'
data.columns = newCols}]
```

Comment: Please post raw input data, code to reproduce your df and the code that produces the error

Comment: proportion_women_survived = float(sum(women.survived))/len(women) This is one example. I read_CSV('Train.csv) into Python editor and the columns are shown when I data.head() however not one column unless I do this   newCols = data.columns.values
newCols[-1] = 'PassengerId'
data.columns = newCols

Comment: it's unclear what specifically is not working? What does `data.columns.tolist()` show?

Comment: `data.columns.tolist()
Out[8]: 
['new_name',
 'Survived',
 'Pclass',
 'Name',
 'Sex',
 'Age',
 'SibSp',
 'Parch',
 'Ticket',
 'Fare',
 'Cabin',
 'Embarked']

Comment: Well your problem is clear it's `'Survived'` not `'survived'` columns are case-sensitive

Comment: I get this when I call the columns ~print data.columns
`Index([u'new_name', u'Survived', u'Pclass', u'Name', u'Sex', u'Age', u'SibSp',
       u'Parch', u'Ticket', u'Fare', u'Cabin', u'Embarked'],
      dtype='object')`

Comment: Given the nature of this is it easy to auto lowercase columns once read via csv?

Comment: `df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()`

Answer (score 2):

You get the error because your column names are case-sensitive, typically you can check what your columns really are by using `df.columns.tolist()` as you're concerned about this you can lower case the columns after loading by using:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()
```

Example:

```
In [203]:
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('aBCd'))
df

Out[203]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, B, C, d]
Index: []

In [204]:    
df.columns.str.lower()

Out[204]:
Index(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], dtype='object')
```